# how to combine two list into Two-dimensional list

Tags: scala

I have two lists, `List(1,2),List(3,4)`

and I want Two-dimensional `List(List(1,2),List(3,4))` like this,how?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
val a = List(1,2)
val b = List(3,4)
val c = List(a,b) // List(List(1,2),List(3,4))
```

Comment: @wangjiweisean if you could click the tick and accept the answer it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

if you really want a List of Lists then @Dionysis answer is ok.
You can use

```
  val a = List(1,2)
  val b = List(3,4)
  a.zip(b) //res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,3), (2,4))
```

if you don´t need that type